# Routing based condtions does not work on iPad device angular4

Tags: angular, ipad

I have using angular4 and In my home page, different header and other pages different header but I have tested my app on iPad this routing based condition does not work. In another page show both header. I have check another all device this work fine.

My Html code is:-

```
<div *ngIf="router?.url == '/home'">
  <h2> Home page </h2>
</div>

<div *ngIf="router?.url != '/home'>
  <h2> Another pages </h2>
</div>
```

ts file code:-

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {
}
```

Please tell us. My app does not work good in the iPad device.

Comment: What exactly does `*ngIf="router?.url == '/home'` do? Do you just have one huge HTML page that changes what it displays based on the router address?

Comment: If router URL is '/home' so display different content and visa verse. This is work on all dervices. But does not work on iPad

Comment: That's not really how the angular router is intended to work. You would normally create a `@Component` for each route and then load that component for each route. The angular `<router-outlet>` does that for you. See https://angular.io/guide/router Unless I've misunderstood what this does.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to Import `ActivatedRoute`

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(public router: ActivatedRoute ) {
}
```

then condition like this

```
<div *ngIf="router.snapshot.url[0].path == 'home'; else AboutPage">
   <h2> Home page </h2>
</div>

<ng-template #AboutPage>
   <h2> Another pages </h2>
</ng-template>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Please tell us without router.snapshot.url[0].

Comment: There are so many pages and All pages different header content.  So that time how it this work. That's, why I have, does not use indexing. like this [0]

Comment: Please share more details about you routes structure